# std.json.parse and memory management

Tags: zig

I have the following zig code (simplified):

```
const allocator = ...;

const Entry = struct {
    name: []u8,
};

fn list() ![]u8 {
    var entries = try std.json.parse([]Entry, ...);
    defer std.json.parseFree([]Entry, entries, ...);
    return entries[0];
}

fn main() !void {
    const e = try list();
    ...
}
```

Everything is (de)allocated with `allocator`.

I'd like to return `entries[0]` and recycle everything else. The problem is that `parseFree` here recycles everything including `entries[0]` so I can't seemingly use this function.

So what's the most effective way to do that without copying? What if `Entry` is a big structure and I want to return just one its field, say `Entry.name` (and, again, recycle everything else)?

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way of achieving what you want is to not use parseFree but instead:

```zig
const first = entries[0].name;
for (entries[1..entries.len]) |e| alloc.free(e.name); // frees individual strings
alloc.free(entries); // frees the array of structs

return Entry { .name = first };
```

This is fairly straightforward but relies on understanding how memory is allocated by std.json **and** the implementation might one day want to allocate things differently, causing the code above to break.

Because of that, my recommendation would be to just copy the string and only resort to this type of extra complexity once you have demonstrated that avoiding that copy brings perceivable benefits.